# Adding columns to a dataframe from another dataframe shows NaN instead of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a two dictionaries of pandas data frames. I am looping through the dictionaries and adding columns from one data frame to the other. Finally, I concatenate all the updated data frames into a single data frame but the columns which were added or updated show NaN instead of values. Here is how I am doing it. Thanks

```
old_id_header = list(l[2][ID].columns)
new_id_header = list(new_dfs_dict[ID].columns)
for i in range(2, len(new_id_header)):
        new_dfs_dict[ID][new_id_header[i]] = new_dfs_dict[ID][new_id_header[i]].astype(float)
        l[2][ID][new_id_header[i]] = new_dfs_dict[ID][new_id_header[i]]
```

Then I am concatenating this way.

```
ready_to_set_df = pd.DataFrame()
for ID in l[2]:
        ready_to_set_df = pd.concat([ready_to_set_df, l[2][ID]], sort=False)
```

Comment: Have you checked the shape of `ready_to_set_df`?  The `pandas.concat` default is to concatenate along the `0` axis (i.e. 'adding new rows').  To concatenate columns you should pass the argument 'axis=1` to the `concat` method.

Comment: I am trying to concatenate horizontally. Can I overwrite columns?

Comment: Yes you can overwrite columns.  However, it sounds like you just need to add `axis=1` to your `concat` statement.

Comment: Yes I did. Let me explain it a little more to you. I have two data frames df1 with columns ['col1', 'col2'] and df2 with columns ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']. I want to concatenate df2 to df1 so as to update col1 and col2 with col1 and col2 from df2 and add col3.

Comment: Are these dataframes of different lengths then?  Because otherwise, if you're taking `col1` and `col2` from `df2` and adding `col3` from `df2`, you are replacing `df1` with `df2` entirely.

Comment: Sounds like you probably want `pd.merge` but it depends on what you mean by 'update' `col1` and `col2`.

Comment: The df2 can have columns ['col2', 'col3']. In this case I want to keep col1 from first frame. By 'update', I simply mean to update the whole column  values with the new. Please note that index columns is always the same for all the frames.

Comment: I also tried 'combine_first' and then 'update'. It somehow changes the order of the columns. Can you explain why and how to avoid sorted version of 'combine_first'?

Comment: In that case, have a look at `pd.merge`.